# Can a Pakistani refugee apply for a US visitor visa?

Tags: visas, usa, italy, pakistani-citizens, refugees

I have a Permesso di Soggiorno (a *Residency Permit*) in Italy; can I apply for an USA visit visa?

I'm from Pakistan, I studied in the UK, left the UK and then illegally came to Italy. I applied for asylum in Italy and got documents of 2 years. Now I want to apply for a USA visit visa.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Can you clarify your question?  Having Permisso di Soggiorno doesn't have anything to do with your ability to apply for a visa.

Comment: Thanks for rapid reply.i have permssio Di saggionor of 2 years

Comment: How long doesn't matter.

Comment: Which country you're a citizen of (if any)? Do you have any other travel document?

Comment: I m from Pakistan, I studied in uk left uk illegally came to Italy , applied asylum in Italy got documents of 2 years. Now I want to apply for USA visit visa 

Comment: You will simply submit your titolo di vaggio per stranieri instead of a passport. Otherwise the process is the same.

Comment: You can apply, but I highly doubt you'll get one considering your history.

Answer (score 4):

[And in English, from the US Mission to Italy, B1 / B2 Visas](https://italy.usembassy.gov/mobile/visa/vis/vis-2-en.html), note last paragraph, emphasis mine:

> The "B" Visitor Visa is a non-immigrant visa for persons desiring to enter the United States temporarily for business (B-1) or temporarily for pleasure (B-2).
>   Persons planning to travel to the U.S. for a different purpose such as students, temporary workers crewmen, journalists, etc., must apply for a different visa in the appropriate category.
>
> **HOW TO QUALIFY FOR A "B" VISA**
>
> Applicants for visitor visas must show that they qualify under provisions of the Immigration and Nationality Act.
>
> The presumption in the law is that every visa applicant is an intending immigrant. Therefore, applicants for visitor visas must overcome this presumption by demonstration that:
>
> -The purpose of their trip is to enter the U.S. for business or pleasure;
>      -They plan to remain for a specific, limited period;
>      -They have a residence outside of the U.S. as well as other binding obligations which will insure their return abroad at the conclusion of the visit.
>
> **OPTIONAL DOCUMENTATION**
>
> Applicants must demonstrate that they are properly classifiable as visitors under U.S. law. Evidence which shows the purpose of the trip, intent to depart the United States, and arrangements made to cover the costs of the trip may be provided. It is impossible to specify the exact form the evidence should take since applicants' circumstances vary greatly. For persons traveling to the U.S. on business, a letter from the business firm indicating the purpose of the trip, the bearer's intended length of stay, and the firm's intent to defray travel costs, is an example of such documentation. For a persons traveling to the U.S. for pleasure, it is necessary to show proof of ties to Italy. Those applicants who do not have sufficient funds to support themselves while in the U.S. must present convincing evidence that an interested person will provide support. Visitors are not permitted to accept employment during their stay in the U.S. depending on individual circumstances, applications may provide other evidence substantiating the purpose of the trip, and specifying the nature of binding obligations, such as family ties or employment, which would compel their return abroad after a short stay.
>
> **TO PROCESS YOUR VISITOR VISA (B-1/B-2) YOU MUST PRESENT THE FOLLOWING DOCUMENTATION:**
>
> - BNL receipt of payment of the non-refundable Machine Readable Visa application fee.
> - The completed visa application form DS-160.
> - A passport valid for travel to the United States. If more than one person is included in the passport, each individual desiring a visa must make a separate application;
> - One passport size photo for each visa applicant, including infants (see the "Photo Requirements" webpage).
>
> ***Any further documentation that demonstrates social, economic, and family ties to Italy and purpose of trip (such documents might include: Permesso di soggiorno in original form for non-Italian citizens, letter of employment, the last pay slip or Form 101, INPS, or Tax Form, marriage certificate for non-Italians married to an Italian citizen, bank statement demonstrating sufficient funds.)***